# iframe width doesnt fit on portrait orientation on mobile

Tags: html, css, iframe, width, responsiveness

I am using the below code for iframe on my website.

```css
.callrates {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 35px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: scroll !important;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;
    height:500px;
}

.callrates iframe {
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="callrates">
    <iframe src="https://www.xyz.php" width="200px" height="0" allowfullscreen=" " frameborder="0" scroll="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

The problem is when I view it from a mobile device in portrait orientation the width of iframe is more than the screen size and therefore makes it scroll horizontally as well as vertically. I want the full width to fit in the screen.   How do I do this?

Comment: The **iframe** has *width* attribute which is 200px and its priority is higher than your CSS **width: 100%**.

Comment: Even if I change that width attribute to any value, it doesn't change anything. Issue still remains. I tried keeping the width attribute blank and even "0" but doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YpZgYm

```
<iframe src="https://www.xyz.php" width="" height="0" allowfullscreen=" " frameborder="0" scroll="no">
```

Update:

May not be the most elegant solution but you can zoom out the iframe content if making the iframe source page responsive isn't an option.

Try adding

```
iframe{
        -ms-zoom: 0.75;
        -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
        -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -o-transform: scale(0.75);
        -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything. It's still the same.

Comment: There will be a scrollbar since you have set overflow: scroll !important; however the width will auto adjust

Comment: There is a scroll bar. But my question was I want the full width iframe to fit in the screen with having a scroll bar for the width. I hope you got my point.

Comment: If the iframe content has a content of lets say 400px and is not responsive. The frame content will still take up 400px width irrespective of the parent frame's width. 

This will have to be controlled at the frame sources CSS.

Comment: Ok. What should be added to the iframe source file?

Comment: Also, the iframe content works fine in the landscape view. Problem is only in the portrait view.

Comment: try using a media query and applying the css fix above

Comment: The CSS fix zooms out only on computer screen, not on the mobile screen. Iframe content remains as it is on a mobile screen.

Comment: In that case the only option you have is to make the frame content responsive